# стилизация текста CSS в Spinner (JavaFX)

Tags: css, javafx

Второй день не могу найти каким образом с помощью CSS поменять свойства текста в Spinner-е. Вроде бы должно работать через такой код, так как в спиннер встроено текстовое поле но не происходит (размер и цвет не меняются). Как побороть эту проблему, может знает кто?

```css
.spinner .text-field{
    -fx-font-size : 14px;
    -fx-text-fill : #ffc41f;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

В общем сам разобрался. Код правильный, все работает. Нашел у себя ошибку (стояла ссылка на другой файл).